# Android app crashes when trying to use variable

Tags: java, android

Hello in my app I have three fragments one of them is a HomeFragment where I fetch all user details from Firebase Realtime database and in the `onDataChange` event I store User data into the User object, but when I try to use info from this object in the button `onClick` event my app crashes.

**Logcat Error**

```
08-01 13:12:51.900 11158-11158/com.cbcwebs.luto.luto D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-01 13:12:51.900 11158-11158/com.cbcwebs.luto.luto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cbcwebs.luto.luto, PID: 11158
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x4d
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:331)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:287)
        at com.cbcwebs.luto.luto.HomeFragment.processUSerBuy(HomeFragment.java:82)
        at com.cbcwebs.luto.luto.HomeFragment$1.onClick(HomeFragment.java:69)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
08-01 13:17:39.606 11158-11186/com.cbcwebs.luto.luto I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
    [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

**HomeFragment**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private  Integer time;
    private  TextView timeLeftView;
    Button btn;
    private Integer currentCoinsUser;

    private Integer currentCoins;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


         getUserInfo();
        btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playLotteryButton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
              processUSerBuy();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
    public  void processUSerBuy() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),currentCoinsUser, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    public void getUserInfo() {
        String UID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
        DatabaseReference mFirebaseDbReferenceUserChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        DatabaseReference mFirebaseDbReferenceCurrentUser= mFirebaseDbReferenceUserChild.child(UID);
        mFirebaseDbReferenceCurrentUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                Userbalance.setText("₹"+user.getUserBalanace());
                Userearning.setText("₹"+user.getUserEarning());
                UserInvest.setText("₹"+user.getUserInvest());
                currentCoins = user.getUserCoins();
                storeUserInfo(currentCoins);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError name) {
            }
        });
    }
   public  void storeUserInfo(Integer currentCoins) {
       currentCoinsUser = currentCoins;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: updated with code

Comment: In the `processUSerBuy()` method, you're passing an integer value to a `Toast.makeText()` call. You need to convert it to a `String` first; e.g., `Integer.toString(currentCoinsUser);`.

Comment: app still crashing

Comment: If you've properly applied my suggestion, then the stack trace should've changed.

Comment: yes now its->  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: how it can be null when assigning  value to this on datachange

Comment: Well, now you're calling it before you've set a value to `currentCoinsUser`. Before, you'd called it when it's value was assigned. You could either initialize `currentCoinsUser` to a non-null value – e.g., `private Integer currentCoinsUser = 0;` – or just make it an `int` instead of a `Integer`.

Comment: can u please suggest me how can i store User Object instead of this Int

Comment: i changed it to Int but now it always show value 0

Comment: 1) Sorry, but that's a different question. However, if you're simply asking how to keep a reference to that `User` within the `Fragment`, you can create a field for that just like you did the coin value. That is, add `private User user;` at the top, and then remove `User` from the beginning of the `User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);` line in `onDataChange()`.

Comment: 2) Then I would say there's something wrong with either your timing, or the Firebase operation, which is a separate question. Feel free to post a new one to ask about that, but make sure to include the code from the start.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer . have a great day :)